# Conceptual understanding of a matrix and matrix vector product

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

When write a set of simultaneous equations as a matrix-vector product of the sort:

$$\mathbf{A} \mathrm{p} = \mathrm{b}$$

(with the right dimensions)

- the left hand side $\mathbf{A} p$ can be thought as a point/vector $p$ mapped onto a new point $b$
- Equation asks which initial point(s) will end up in $b$.

The mapping can be easily seen from the linear combination of columns:

$$A_1 p_1 + A_2 p_2 + \ldots + A_n p_n$$

- If $b$ is not this span of the columns of A, then there is no solution.

**Basic Questions**

1. How to think about this when $P$ is a matrix ?
2. Is each point (column vector) $P_i$ similarly mapped to a new location in the $A$ space, and we search in turn for the $P_i$'s that get mapped onto $b_i$ but independently?
3. Would this systems of equations be actually related though ? My point being that now each row of P seems to belong to a different, unrelated set of equations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $P$ is a matrix (and "$B$" also) every column of $P$ is transformed and its new (transformed) vector replaces the column (resulting in the column in $B$). In other words, you solve every column of $P$ for the corresponding column of $B$.

Comment: Yes, but in the case of a single one $p$ the equations are clearly dependent, but if it is a matrix, we have independent set of equations right ? There is no relationship between them

Comment: You get several independent *sets* of dependent equations.